# Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso

Tags: c#

estoy armando un programa en C# a través del cual quiero guardar datos en un archivo txt. Cuando intento hacerlo, me lanza una excepcion de "Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso". Lo raro es que tambien estoy guardando un archivo xml en la misma carpeta y no tuve ningún inconveniente. De hecho, probé leer desde archivo el mismo txt situado en la carpeta en cuestión, y la lectura no falla para nada, el problema es solo en la escritura. El error me lo tira al crear el objeto StreamWriter. Ya intente desde la carpeta habilitar los permisos de lectura y escritura pero sigo teniendo fallas. Copio el código. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! El código se comparte como texto, así como nadie te va a responder con imágenes para que transcribas la solución. Replicar tu problema es mucho más difícil así. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Me sumo al comentario de Alfabravo y le agrego otra lectura recomendada:  [algunas razones por las que debes incluir el código en texto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/182188) y no como imagen.

Comment: Hola Leandro, concuerdo con lo que dicen Pablo y Alfabravo. Asimismo, cuando agregues el codigo como texto, muestranos también tu clase "Jornada"

Comment: Hola a todos. Perdon por el error, es mi primer publicacion y no estaba al tanto de ciertas cosas. Voy a revisar las lecturas que me recomiendan antes de continuar. De todas maneras les comento que pude solucionar el inconveniente. Tuve que eliminar el “.txt” del path y de esa forma puede trabajar con el archivo en modo lectura y escritura. Muchas gracias x las respuestas.